# How can I create a multicolumn and multirow tables in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %to plot figure
\usepackage{array, blkarray, tabularx, longtable, multirow,threeparttable, makecell, booktabs, caption} 
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %to plot figure
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % default is 6pt
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\textbf{#1}}%  to make heads of table in BOLD, it is used with booktabs package and \head
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url} \makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds} \makeatother
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm} % needed for command eqref or Math packages
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true
   ,breaklinks
   %, ngerman
    ] {hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the docuent, the option colorlink=true gets rid of the awful boxes, breaklinks breaks lonk links (list of figures), and the ngerman sets everthing for german s default hyperlink languages.
\definecolor {c1}{rgb}{0,0, 1} % blue
\definecolor {c2}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % light blue
\definecolor {c3}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % red blue
\hypersetup{
   linkcolor={c1}, % internal links
    citecolor={c2}, % citations 
    urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
}
\usepackage{longtable} % needed for long tables over pages
\usepackage{bigstrut} % needed for the  command \bigstrut
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{makeidx}  % needed for creating an index
\usepackage{blindtext} % needed for creating dummy text passage
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[T]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,
                    labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[table]{font={footnotesize,sc},
                      labelsep=newline,
                      justification=centering}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*, fill=white}}
                \draw [densely dashed,blue] (marker-|0,0) -- (0,0);
                \draw plot [mark=*] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
             \else
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
             \fi
        }{
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}        
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
        \begin{scope}[options]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother

%% page settings%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry} % needed for page border stteings 
\parindent=0cm % for spece of first line of new text block
\sloppy % for writing with hypenless justification (tries to)
%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliograph style

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\parindent 0ex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead {}
\frenchspacing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \MakeUppercase {Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) in Ethiopia}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}%This affects the in spacing of my paragraphes
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparing Ethiopian Regulatory \\Performance with selected SSA countries}
\label{table1}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}||p{6cm}|p{6cm} |p{6cm} |p{6cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{Country} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Over all Ranking} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Basic Requirement} &
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Efficiency Enablers} & 
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Innov. and Sophis. Factors} \\
 \hline
Economy & Rank & Score & Rank & Score & Rank & Score & Rank & Score
 \\ 
 \hline 
 Tunisia &  95 & 3.92 &  79 & 4.41  & 103 & 3.65 & 104 & 3.32\\
 \hline
 Kenya   &  96 & 3.9   & 115 & 3.81 & 75  & 4.03 & 40 &  4.03\\
 \hline

 Ethiopia & 109 & 3.77 & 106 & 3.96 & 117 & 3.47 & 74 & 3.53
  \\ \hline
 Cape Verde & 110 & 3.76 & 89 & 4.32 & 121 & 3.40 & 105 & 3.32
  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
--------
-------
\end{document}
```

My purpose is to produce a 6 (row) by 5 (column) table first and then split the 4 columns to the right each into two. I tried as can be seen from the above effort. However, LaTeX gives me an error which says "extra alignment table has been changed to \cr. \endtemplate\multicolum...
you have given more \span & marks than there were in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress..."

I exerted a strenuous endeavour  yet I failed and hence I am kindly requesting for your kindl help. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: You can't split columns. You only can merge them. So you have to declare 9 columns. Furthermore, even the 5 column widths you declare can't fit  a landscape A4 paper page.

Comment: @Masroor Thanks for your great help. Can you please explicate how to improve what I tried in more detail.

Comment: @HailaiWeldeslassie Please see the great answer already provided. Please try to understand each and every dot in the solution. That will help you in future occasions. To learn on the basics of `tabular` please study these (any one or preferably all), [1](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/tables), [2](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/beginners/latex-tables/), [3](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/LaTeX/TableHelp1.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I propose this layout, which requires `hhline` and `siunitx` for the alignment of numbers in tables (`S` column type). I took the opportunity to slightly reorganise your preamble (some packages were loaded twice, `hyperref` should be the last loaded package with very few exceptions most notably `cleveref`, language file should be loaded as an option of the document class).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\usepackage{blkarray, tabularx, longtable, multirow,threeparttable, makecell, booktabs, hhline, caption}
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" column type
% \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % default is 6pt
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\textbf{#1}}% to make heads of table in BOLD, it is used with booktabs package and \head
\usepackage{url} \makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds} \makeatother
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm} % needed for command eqref or Math packages
\usepackage{bigstrut} % needed for the command \bigstrut
\usepackage{enumerate} % needed for some options in enumerate
\usepackage{makeidx} % needed for creating an index
\usepackage{blindtext} % needed for creating dummy text passage
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,
                    labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[table]{font={footnotesize, sc},
                      labelsep=newline,
                      justification=centering}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots, pgfplotstable} %to plot figure
\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discontinuous/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*, fill=white}}
                \draw [densely dashed,blue] (marker-|0,0) -- (0,0);
                \draw plot [mark=*] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
             \else
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
             \fi
        }{
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
        \begin{scope}[options]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother

%% page settings%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=1.8cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry} % needed for page border stteings
\parindent=0cm % for spece of first line of new text block
\sloppy % for writing with hypenless justification (tries to)
%\usepackage[round, authoryear]{natbib} % needed for cite and abbrvnat bibliograph style

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true
   ,breaklinks
   %, ngerman
    ] {hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the docuent, the option colorlink=true gets rid of the awful boxes, breaklinks breaks lonk links (list of figures), and the ngerman sets everything for german s default hyperlink languages.
\definecolor {c1}{rgb}{0,0, 1} % blue
\definecolor {c2}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % light blue
\definecolor {c3}{rgb}{0.3,0.3, 0.9} % red blue
\hypersetup{
   linkcolor={c1}, % internal links
    citecolor={c2}, % citations
    urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
}
\usepackage{cleveref}%% to be loaded after hyperref
%\parindent 0ex
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead {}
\frenchspacing
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \MakeUppercase {Multidimensional Poverty Index (MPI) in Ethiopia}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}%This affects the in spacing of my paragraphs
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theadset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\centering\sisetup{table-alignment=center, table-column-width =2.4cm}
\setlength\doublerulesep{4pt}
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparing Ethiopian Regulatory Performance with selected SSA countries}
\label{table1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |X||*{3}{S[table-format=3.0]| >{}S[table-format=1.2]||}S[table-format=3.0]| >{}S[table-format=1.2]|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Economy}\\
\hhline{~||--||--||--||--|}
\multicolumn{1}{c!{\phantom{\vrule}\vrule}}{} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c||}{Over all Ranking} &
\multicolumn{2}{c||}{Basic Requirement} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c||}{Efficiency Enablers} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Innov. and Sophis. Factors} \\
\hhline{|~||--||--||--||--|}
\addlinespace[4pt]
\hhline{|-||--||--||--||--|}
Country& {Rank} & {Score} & {Rank} & {Score} & {Rank }& {Score} & {Rank} & {Score}
 \\
\hhline{|-||--||--||--||--|}
 Tunisia & 95 & 3.92 & 79 & 4.41 & 103 & 3.65 & 104 & 3.32\\
\hhline{|-||--||--||--||--|}
 Kenya & 96 & 3.9 & 115 & 3.81 & 75 & 4.03 & 40 & 4.03\\
\hhline{|-||--||--||--||--|}
 Ethiopia & 109 & 3.77 & 106 & 3.96 & 117 & 3.47 & 74 & 3.53 \\
\hhline{|-||--||--||--||--|}
 Cape Verde & 110 & 3.76 & 89 & 4.32 & 121 & 3.40 & 105 & 3.32 \\
\hhline{|-||--||--||--||--|}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: =Million thanks for your vital and insightful help. I tried as per your kind recommendations, yet,  it failed and the error reported is "! Undefined control sequence." what can I do Sir?

Comment: What is the ‘undefined control sequence’ in the error message? It probably corresponds to a package you didn't load (I added  `siunitx` and `hhline`).

Comment: Thanks again. ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \hhline
l.333 \end{tabularx}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit
...... these are some of the error reports and still not fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much again. It perfectly worked and what I was looking for is definitely answered. God bless

Comment: I've just found your last two messages. Finally you have solbed the problem? The errormessage you showed is related to  `hhline`, so I suppose loading the package solved the problem. Correct?